# I am learning design patterns. Can you help me design a factory pattern for this class?

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have a class built from a hierarchy of other classes, and I had created a bunch of the same classes that looked identical other than the class name

for example

```
class Class1 extends BaseClass
{
  public function __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();
  }
}

class Class2 extends BaseClass
{
  public function __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();
  }
}

class Class3 extends BaseClass
{
  public function __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

But I realize (hopefully rightfully) that I could create Class[1-3] using a factory pattern, and just pass a class name and have the factory return one of these classes.  This would require much less code, thus more maintainable.  Also, how would you suggest implementing if say I wanted to do this :

```
class Class4 extends AnotherBaseClass
{
  public function __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

note that class 4 extends another base class, but it is the exact same other than a small bit of information that AnotherBaseClass holds.

right now i am thinking something like this (my thoughts are fuzzy and incomplete at this point):

//where i am putting the repeating code

```
class Skeleton extends BaseClass
{
  public function __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();
  }
}


class ClassFactory
{
   public function __construct( $className , $classType )
   {
      <pseudocode>
      Class5 = new $className
      ???and some how make $className extend $classType ???
      return class5
      </pseudocode>
   }

}
```

Is the factory pattern the correct answer?

Cheers!

Comment: "I had created a bunch of the same classes that looked identical other than the class name" - Don't ever do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - factory pattern is the correct answer. In addition you may also check out [Abstract Factory](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory), specifically for the scenario you mentioned where your some classes will have different attributes and may derive from some other base class.